# Magento 2 Pagination for custom collection in Admin Grid using Layout is not working

Tags: magento-2.1

I am trying to add an array to collection using DataObject in Admin Grid. The pagination options(html) top of the grid rendered correct but, the grid shows all the records irrespective of the number of rows to be visible per page.

For example i have 100 records, per page count as 20, divided to 5 pages. Navigating to any of the pages shows total 100 records.

```
class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended {
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Data $backendHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $dataCollection,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_dataCollection = $dataCollection;
    parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
}

protected function _construct() {
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setId('system_grid');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    $this->setDefaultSort('id');
    $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
    $this->setLimitVarName('limit');
    $this->setPageVarName('page');      
}

protected function _prepareCollection() {
     $data = [
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'product_name' => "Some Value"
        ],
        [
            'id' => 2,
            'product_name' => "Some Another Value"
        ],
        ........100 records
    ];
    $collection = $this->_dataCollection;  
    foreach ($logData as $data) {
        $varienObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $varienObject->setData($data);
        $collection->addItem($varienObject);
    }

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
}
```

Can anyone please help to resolve the pagination issue?